# Graphic Design History

Tags: designers, history

Can anyone explain the reasons that make the modernity of the 1950s and 1960s seem outdated in graphic design now?

Comment: Way too broad question. And not sure that's entirely outdated. Who says that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking this question, you need to read the Meggs.

Philip B. Meggs & Alston W. Purivs: Megg's History of Graphic Design.

[Wiley dot com Megg's History of Graphic Design](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Meggs%27+History+of+Graphic+Design%2C+6th+Edition-p-9781119136231)

Definitive, thorough and well researched.

A benchmark.

Hope this helps.